# Packet tracer IGRP configuration

Tags: networking

I am using packet tracer 5.3 version and I am trying to configure IGRP on it but it doesn't show me igrp under routing protocol selection.Router number is 2621XM.IOS version is 12.2.

```
Router(config)#router ?
  bgp    Border Gateway Protocol (BGP)
  eigrp  Enhanced Interior Gateway Routing Protocol (EIGRP)
  ospf   Open Shortest Path First (OSPF)
  rip    Routing Information Protocol (RIP)
```

Please help me to learn the configuration of IGRP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Source: [Packet Tracer FAQ PDF](http://www.cisco.com/web/learning/netacad/downloads/pdf/PT5_1_FAQ_Dec08.pdf)

If your learning material is still teaching IGRP, it's probably time to get newer editions of them.

Answer (score 1):

IGRP is no longer supported by New release of Cisco IOS 12.1 version.
Thats why you are not able to run the following command on cisco packet tracer. you can use EIGRP instead of IGRP.

R(config)#router igrp 10